# PerformSegueWithIdentifier not working consistently

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm not using any navigation controller in my project. This project is taken online is sidebar menu for Swift. In the sidebar menu, there is a table view and each row will `performSegueWithIdentifier`.

**Problem:**

First few clicks on tableViewCell works like a charm, it can dismiss menu just a single click. But afterward, need to double click the tableViewCell in order to dismiss the menu.

Required two clicks to dismiss menu: (First click on tableViewCell, the viewController will disappear, second click on tableViewCell will dismiss the menu)

**NavigationViewController(Sidebar Menu)**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    self.snapshot.removeFromSuperview()
    var segueName: NSString = "";

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        print("ROW 1")
        segueName = "listview"

    }
    if (indexPath.row == 1) {
        print("CLICK ROW 2")
        segueName = "othernav"
    }

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier(segueName as String, sender: self)
}
```

**Storyboard**

[image]

Resources are taken from [here](http://www.appdesignvault.com/custom-transition-slide-out-navigation/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it with:

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {});
```

Here are some informations about the "bug". But I thought Apple fixed it...

http://openradar.appspot.com/19563577

Your code should look like this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
self.snapshot.removeFromSuperview()
var segueName: NSString = "";

if (indexPath.row == 0) {
    print("ROW 1")
    segueName = "listview"

}
if (indexPath.row == 1) {
    print("CLICK ROW 2")
    segueName = "othernav"
}

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {}); 
self.performSegueWithIdentifier(segueName as String, sender: self)
}
```

If this doesn't work you could try this:

Replace

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {}); 
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier(segueName as String, sender: self)
```

with:

```
   NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock {
              self.performSegueWithIdentifier(segueName as String, sender: self) }
```